# resolution - satisfiability of formula (edit: renaming clause variables)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs, satisfiability

I need to determine whether the following formula is satisfiable, using binary resolution:

$$\exists x \forall y \forall z ((P(y) \to Q(z)) \to (P(x) \to Q(x)))$$

I re-framed the problem to showing that the [above] formula's negation is unsatisfiable:

$\lnot\exists x \forall y \forall z ((P(y) \to Q(z)) \to (P(x) \to Q(x)))$ `negation of the [original] formula`

$\forall x  \lnot ((P(g(x)) \to Q(h(x))) \to (P(x) \to Q(x)))$ `skolemized: y = g(x) & z = h(x)`

$\forall x ((\lnot P(g(x)) \lor Q(h(x))) \land P(x) \land (\lnot Q(x)))$ `converted to CNF`

Now, it is clear that I cannot derive an empty clause from the set of clauses $$\{[\lnot P(g(x)), Q(h(x))], \, [P(x)], \, [\lnot Q(x)] \}$$ **Does this mean that the negation of the [original] formula is satisfiable?**

---

But I'm unable to derive an empty clause even using the original formula:

$\exists x \forall y \forall z ((P(y)  \to Q(z)) \to (P(x) \to Q(x)))$ `original formula`

$\forall y \forall z ((P(y) \to  Q(z)) \to (P(a) \to Q(a)))$ `skolemized: x = a`

$\forall y \forall z ((P(y) \lor \lnot P(a) \lor Q(a)) \land (\lnot Q(z) \lor \lnot P(a) \lor Q(a))$ `converted to CNF`

Now, again clearly I cannot derive an empty clause from the set of clauses
$$\{[P(y), \lnot P(a), Q(a)], \, [\lnot Q(z), \lnot P(a), Q(a)] \}$$ **Does this mean that the satisfiability of the [original] formula cannot be determined?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the formula

$$\tag{1} \exists x \forall y \forall z \big( (P(y) \to Q(z)) \to (P(x) \to Q(x)) \big)$$

is valid, which means that *every* structure satisfies it. In particular, it is satisfiable.

This is because, by applying the resolution method to the *negation* of the formula $(1)$, it is possible to get the empty clause. Hence, the *negation* of $(1)$ is unsatisfiable, which amounts to say that $(1)$ is valid.

Your syntactical handling starting from the negation of $(1)$ is correct, eventually you get the clauses:

\begin{align}
\{¬P(g(x)), Q(h(x))\} && \{P(x)\} && \{¬ Q(x)\}
\end{align}
and after renaming the free variables so that distinct clauses have no variables in common (all variables in a clause are implicitly universally quantified, hence renaming does not change satisfiability), you get

\begin{align}
\tag{2}
\{¬P(g(x)), Q(h(x))\} && \{P(y)\} && \{¬ Q(z)\}
\end{align}

You can resolve the first two clauses on $(2)$ thanks to the MGU $\{y \leftarrow g(x)\}$, thus the resolvent is the clause

\begin{align}
\tag{3}
\{Q(h(x))\}
\end{align}

You can resolve the clause $(3)$ with the third clause in $(2)$ thanks to the MGU $\{z \leftarrow h(x)\}$, and the resolvent is the empty clause $\square$.
Since there is a way to derive the empty clause by repeating the resolution method, the *negation* of $(1)$ is unsatisfiable and hence $(1)$ is valid, in particular $(1)$ is satisfiable.

---

EDIT. Note that the formula
$$\forall x \big((\lnot P(g(x))\lor Q(h(x)))\land P(x) \land \lnot Q(x) \big) $$
(the CNF you correctly wrote in the OP) is logically equivalent to
$$\forall x (\lnot P(g(x))\lor Q(h(x))) \land \forall x P(x) \land \forall x\lnot Q(x)$$
which is the same as
$$\forall x (\lnot P(g(x))\lor Q(h(x))) \land \forall y P(y) \land \forall z\lnot Q(z).$$

This the logical reason that explains why the clauses
\begin{align}
\{¬P(g(x)), Q(h(x))\} && \{P(x)\} && \{¬ Q(x)\}
\end{align}
can be rewritten as in $(2)$ above, after renaming the free variables so that distinct clauses have no variables in common.

Comment: Isn't the formula $\forall x, y, z ((\lnot P(g(x)) \lor Q(h(x))) \land P(y) \land (\lnot Q(z)))$  different from $\forall x ((\lnot P(g(x)) \lor Q(h(x))) \land P(x) \land (\lnot Q(x)))$. And if they are equivalent, would the formula $\forall x, y ((\lnot P(g(x)) \lor Q(h(y))) \land P(x) \land (\lnot Q(x)))$ be equivalent to these two formulae? I would like to know the rules that inform this kind of variable renaming.

Comment: @harshatech2012 - A formula $\forall x (A \land B)$ is equivalent to the formula $(\forall x A) \land (\forall x B)$, hence $A$ and $B$ (which represent two distinct clauses in a CNF) can be instantiated independently. This is why it is legitimate to rename the free variables of distinct clauses so that they have no variables in common. To understand better the theory behind the resolution method for first-order logic, see [here](https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/piskac/teaching/decpro-729/fol.pdf), in particular pages 40-48.

Comment: adding to what you said - see slides 6-9 and 26 in https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-825-techniques-in-artificial-intelligence-sma-5504-fall-2002/lecture-notes/Lecture8FinalPart1.pdf